# Awk with function calling error in redirection

Tags: function, redirect, awk

```
awk -F "|" 'function decToBin(dec) { printf "ibase=10; obase=2; $dec" | bc; } BEGIN {print $3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "decToBin($8)}' $Input
```

where Input is the path to file having

```
1|2|1.00|0.46|0.44|1.12|49.88|3
2|2|1.00|0.45|0.55|1.13|50.12|11
```

It was working correctly without function calling but after introducing function decToBin() it gives error. it gives error as

```
awk: fatal: expression for `|' redirection has null string value
```

got stuck dont know how to do that
please need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

myawkscript.awk:

```
function decToBin(dec) {
    cmd="echo 'ibase=10; obase=2;" dec ";'|bc";
    cmd|getline var
    return var
}

//{print $3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "decToBin($8)}
```

Then

```
gawk -F"|" -f myawkscript.awk myfile
```

Gives you

```
1.00 0.46 0.44 1.12 49.88 11
1.00 0.45 0.55 1.13 50.12 1011
```

as expected

Comment: Thanks Dude! just let me know one thing
gawk -F"|" -f myscript.awk $Input > $Input 
why it does not redirect the output to same file??

Comment: Because you can't redirect a file into itself; redirecting truncates the target file *before* the command starts. So the command sees an empty input file.

Comment: Okay Thanks!
Could i modify myawkscript.awk such to get 1011 as 1 0 1 1
Please if you have any idea let me know...

Comment: just wrap decToBin($8) in another function that inserts the space. In shell echo "hello" | sed "s/\(.\)/\1 /g" return "h e l l o"

Answer (score 1):

This can't work. `bc` is taken as the name of a variable, not the name of a command (awk doesn't behave like the shell). As the variable is undefined, it is treated as the null string. You must quote the command name:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "1+1\n" | "bc"}' /dev/null
2
```

In addition, `$dec` is not the value of `dec`, but the value of *field number dec*. Again, awk is not the shell. What you rather want it something like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {dec = 21; printf "%d+%d\n", dec, dec | "bc"}' /dev/null
42
```